# Check if point belongs to square

Tags: c, distance, point, rectangles

I want to check if a point **P(x1,y1)** belongs , is inside , a square with center **C(x,y)** and horizontal diagonal **r**.

- Square with the above characteristics:

[image]

- Function that calculates the distance between two points

  ```
  float calculate_distance (float x1,float y1,float x2 ,float y2)
  {
    float distance;
    float distance_x = x1-x2;
    float distance_y = y1- y2;
    distance = sqrt( (distance_x * distance_x) + (distance_y * distance_y));
    return distance;
  }
  ```

Comment: Always (\*) prefer `double` (rather than `float`) for floating point variables. (\*) Yes, always!

Comment: math.stackexchange.com has similar questions. [How to check if a point is inside a rectangle?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190111/how-to-check-if-a-point-is-inside-a-rectangle)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the Euclidian distance between points here.

Just as for a circle (at the origin) you know that x<sup>2</sup>+y<sup>2</sup> is some constant (r<sup>2</sup>), here you know that |x|+|y| is some constant (r again), which is even simpler. Actually you can interpolate between these shapes by using exponents between 1 and 2.

So to check whether a point (x,y) is inside the diamond (which without loss of generality can be assumed to be centered on the origin), just test

```
fabsf(x)+fabsf(y) <= r
```